# SMS Alerts for Important Mails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

What I would like to do is to receive SMS alerts on my phone when I receive important mails in Gmail (**important as filtered by GMails Priority Inbox feature** - search: "is:important" in Gmail). I found this neat little instruction (which work,s except for the additional features I would like to implement) by techawakening.org (http://techawakening.org/free-sms-alerts-new-email-on-gmail-with-google-docs/1130/) and tried to build on that, but due to me not having a technical background I did not succeed (yet). Another thing I tried to build into the script is the option to specify a certain calendar (the script utilizes google calendar for the sms alerts) the reminder-events should be saved to (I prefer to not have them clutter up my default main calendar).

Here is what I came up with:

```
function sendsms() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("sendsms");
  var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
    var firstThread = firstThread.isImportant();
    var firstThread = firstThread.addLabel(label);

var threads = label.getThreads();
var now = new Date().getTime();
for(i in threads){
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var sender= message.getFrom();
  CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('Invisible').createEvent(threads[0].getFirstMessageSubject() + " By: "+sender,new Date(now+60000),new Date(now+60000)).addSmsReminder(0);
  }
  label.removeFromThreads(threads);
}
```

Can anybody here help me?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Phil

Comment: The following post just shows you how to set it up from the gmail website
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-setup-free-sms-alerts-for-urgent-emails-in-gmail/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately those eMail to SMS gateways do not work with my carrier here in Germany. And additionaly this can not be applied to Important Mails (as filtered by Priority Inbox) because searches witrh "is:" (e.g. is:important) according to Gmail never applies to incoming mail. But thanks again. Do you have any ideas on making the above work?

Comment: interesting idea. What isn't working about your code? From a high level perspective it looks okay.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you see any error ? Do you receive SMS notifications on calendar events that you've added manually?

Comment: Thanks for your comments: I do get the original techawakening script to work, so the problem is only regarding the changes I made myself. When I run my script I get the following error message: "TypeError: Cannot find function addLabel in object false." for the following line        var firstThread = firstThread.addLabel(label);

Comment: With the following code;     var cal = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarById('id');
    cal.createEvent(threads[0].getFirstMessageSubject() + " By: "+sender,new Date(now+60000),new Date(now+60000)).addSmsReminder(0); I can specify a certain calendar :) any ideas for the problem of the important mails above?

Comment: I just answered a similar question [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848383/ ] -- you can use the free IFTTT service [ http://ifttt.com ] to send out SMS messages upon receiving emails matching certain criteria.